# Strong params on nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm having a problem when specifying a nested param in the strong param whitelist

whitelisting with `permit!` works

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit!
end
```

but specifying the param fails

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, ......, role_ids: [])
end
```

error: unpermitted params role_ids: []

My models:

```
Roles: 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

Users:
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

join table: roles_users
```

[habtm error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGCNu.png)

I added a console screenshot. It an habtm error (displaying like a link)

Thank you..
finally found an answer
create

```
@user = User.new(sign_up_params)
@user.role_ids = params[:user][:role_ids]
```

Comment: rails version?, also can you add what is in params in the controller?

Comment: Rails version 5.1

Comment: params appear in the server log after each request

Comment: controller params params.require(:user).permit(:username,:email, :password, :password_confirmation, role_ids: [])

Answer (score 0):

It seems have problem in your model relation. It need change to below:

```
users:
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles


roles:
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```